# Changes not reflecting on EAR in WebSphere Application Server after syncNode?

Tags: websphere

We needed to test a functionality on WebSphere.

While the dmgr had the updated code, we needed the old code.
So we stopped auto synchronization, restored the old EAR from backup and copied the EAR to the profiles/installedApps/cell/ directory while all the while having backup of the new EAR in the same directory (with a different name like EAR_bkp).

After the testing was done, we enabled auto synch again and ran a syncNode command to manually sync the EAR, but we are unable to see the new changes. We see the EAR file imported to nodeagents/cells/applications directory but changes are not reflecting on the profiles/installedApps/cell/ directory.

What could be the issue? Please suggest.

Comment: You can always run `Full resynchronize` option instead of just `Synchronize`. It will rescan all the files in dmgr.

Comment: Hi Gas, So the problem is there are certain files on the app server that does not come with the dmgr.  When I synchronize dmgr and appserver, the dmgr just updates the files that has changed. But the extra files on the appserver should remain untouched and just BE there. Will the Full Synchronize option be able to sync the updated code on dmgr with appserver WITHOUT losing those extra files on the app server?

Comment: Also , I did a Full Synchronize with the node. But there are files missing within app. Logs:
FileRepositor A   ADMR0012I: The repository epoch is refreshed.
NodeSyncTask  A   ADMS0003I: The configuration synchronization completed successfully.

Comment: I dont understand what you are trying to do. You should never change files directly in the app server or dmgr directory structure, but always update application via console or scripting. Synchronization is always from dmgr to app servers, so any changes you did on app servers directories will be lost.

Comment: @Gas So all I need to know is if the directory structure or files are different in the app server and dmgr, then full synchronize should update the app EAR exactly the same as how it's in the dmgr config, correct?

Answer (score 0):

WebSphere ND has management tools for handling a variety of application updates without having to tinker in the directories on the dmgr or nodes directly,  Applications > Application Types > WebSphere enterprise applications, then select the app, then click Update.  There are several options described in the attached link.  Also look at the Rollout Update option mentioned on the same page.

[Application update from console](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/trun_app_upgrade_console.html)

Comment: The application is already updated in the dmgr, there is a complete application deployed there. But while syncing the files with the nodes, we see folders missing.